# asigne instancing verts

Tags: armory

I made a chain armor. Now i want to asigne my chain, so that I can delete my base.
[image]
So here you can see on the right side my base. On the left side you see my chain armor. My problem is, that I want to see a little bit trough the chain armor (as in reality).
[image]
But when I try to asigne the object parent with clear parent and ceep transformation, this happens:
[image]
Its not a option to make the base transparent, because this would use more processor performance and I make this mesh for a game.
So how can I do it?
I tryed to asigne all transformation and all modifier and after that, I tryed to clear parents with ceep transfromation, but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find it out. For all that have the same question. Here is there answer. You have to asigne all modifiers, and after that with ctrl a all scales, rotation etc. After that, you first select the origin of the chain aromr, than the base. With ctrl you get this picture
[image]
Then select make instance real or press M
Finally you got all the chain links seperate. Now select all chain links and with ctrl j convert it to one mesh.
[image: Here you can see right on the top, that i have to meshes, the chain armor and the base]
Now you can delete the base.